# Commuting square valuation ring -- morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. For a fixed $x\in X$, let $K=k(x)$. If $y'$ is a specialization of $y=f(x)$, we may choose a valuation ring $R$ of $K$ dominating $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\{y\}},y'}$. This translates into morphisms $\operatorname{Spec}K\to X$ and $g\colon \operatorname{Spec}R\to Y$. I would like to know why the square involving these maps, the inclusion $\operatorname{Spec}K \subset \operatorname{Spec}R$ and $f$ commutes.

We may assume $Y$ to be affine, $Y=\operatorname{Spec}A$ say. Then the above statement becomes:
The composition $h$ of $f^\ast$ with the canonical map $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \to K$ is equal to the composition of $g^\ast$ with the inclusion $R\subset K$.
To see this, I would like to prove that the image of $h$ is contained in $R$. Unfortunately, I don't get far: if not $h(a) \in R$, then $h(a)^{-1} \in R$. Am I missing some detail or assumption?

This question is related to Hartshorne, chapter II, second half of the proof of theorem 4.7.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is where Hartshorne applies Lemma 4.4; is your issue with the proof of Lemma 4.4?

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Thanks for your comment. I understand the proof of Lemma 4.4, but I just don't see why the square described above commutes. Topologically this is clear, but how do I see this on the level of sheaves?

Comment: @TakumiMurayama The problem I have is that the inclusion $k(x_1) \subseteq K$ in Lemma 4.4 does depend on the local homomorphism obtained from the morphism $\operatorname{Spec}K \to X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $x \in X$ be a point, and let $K = k(x)$. We want to show we can construct a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
  \operatorname{Spec} K @>>> X\\
  @ViVV @VVfV\\
  \operatorname{Spec} R @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
where $R$ is a valuation ring of $K$.

The idea is to *define* the map $\operatorname{Spec} R \to Y$ such that the diagram above commutes.

So let $y'$ be a specialization of $y = f(x)$, and let $R$ be a valuation ring of $K$ dominating $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\{y\}},y'}$, where $\overline{\{y\}}$ has the reduced induced subscheme structure. We have a map
$$\operatorname{Spec} R \longrightarrow Y$$
from Lemma 4.4 by choosing $y',y$ to be our points $x_0,x_1$, and using the inclusion of fields $k(y) \subseteq K$ we get from the composition 
$$\operatorname{Spec} K \longrightarrow X \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} Y$$
by Lemma 4.4. But then, the map
$$\operatorname{Spec} K \longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} R \longrightarrow Y$$
corresponds to the same inclusion of fields $k(y) \subseteq K$ by construction.